# how to display table data or pass view  data on site.master page in asp mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

i want to show my table data  on site.master page and display that data all action method plz any one help me or give me sample code  my model and controller code is here

```
    namespace DomainModel.Entities
  {

    [Table(Name = "Requirements")]
public class Requirement

  {
public int  RequirementID{ get; set; }
 [Column] public int Experience { get; set; }
 [Column] public string JobTitle { get; set; }
 [Column] public string Qualification { get; set; }
 [Column] public string Location { get; set; }
 [Column] public int Budget { get; set; }
 [Column] public DateTime Date { get; set; } 
      }

       }
```

my Repository code is here

```
namespace DomainModel.Concrete
 {
public class SqlCandidateRepository : ICandidateRepository
{

 private Table<Requirement> Requirementtable;

  public SqlCandidateRepository(string connectionString)
    {

  Requirementtable = (new DataContext(connectionString)).GetTable<Requirement>();

   public IQueryable<Requirement> NewRequirement()
    { 
    return  from d in Requirementtable where d.Date>=System.DateTime.Now select d;

    }
```

here is my controller code

```
  public ActionResult ShownewRequirement()
    {

     ViewData[" requirement"] = IcandidateRepository.NewRequirement();
      return View();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 Good question.

Since master pages do not take any models. To be able to access data from within your master pages use ViewData (or ViewBag if ASP.NET MVC3) within a base controller.

In all controllers that will use that master page in the views they populate, I make those controllers children of a base controller, let's call it `BaseController`.

Example:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseController()
    {
        ViewData["MyName"] = "LordCover";
    }
}
```

Now, in your master page's markup, you can use this:

```
<h2>Hello <%: ViewData["MyName"] %>!</h2>
```

The output will be:

## Hello LordCover!

I repeat, to make all of your controllers get advantage of this controller they must inherit from it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: hi Lordcover i try it but it is not work the output only hello it not show viewdata

Comment: @Sandy Post your controller definition code and its constructor.

Comment: it is working fine when i inherits the base controller into my all controller thanks LordCover

Comment: but i want display ViewData in specific position bu it is display only top of the master page

Comment: As long as it worked, now it is a matter of interface and some CSS knowledge. Feel free to ask another question about that but be specific, I mean, posting code is something good but you have to explain what you're trying to do, what problems/errors you get...etc.

Comment: hi Lord the viewData display Top on the master page but i want to display Right side on the page any idea

Comment: @Sandy I guarantee that you can get an answer to your question on http://stackoverflow.com but put it in the right place (ask a new question).

Comment: i use parameter base constructor an i was inherits base controller it is show error. my base controller code is here  public abstract class BaseController : Controller
    {
       
       private ICandidateRepository icandidateRepository;
      
        public BaseController( ICandidateRepository icandidateRepository)
        {this.icandidateRepository=icandidateRepository;}}}